# localhost does not resolve for elasticsearch on port 9200, but resolves for MAMP on port 8888

Tags: elasticsearch, localhost, mamp

I have installed MAMP on my OSX Yosemite as a localhost, and it has been working fine -- browser/command line can resolve localhost on port 8888 perfectly.

Yesterday I installed `elasticsearch` using `homebrew`, as well as ES-PHP client, composer, and Marvel, but run in to a weird problem when I started testing ES on localhost:

I issued the command on ES: `curl -X GET http://localhost:9200` on terminal, it gets stuck  -- there is no output, and I have to control-C to get out.

But if I do `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:9200`, I got the perfect output from ES:

> ```
> {
>   "status" : 200,
>   "name" : "Human Cannonball",
>   "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_jay",
>   "version" : {
> ```

(I am omitting the rest of the output.)

It seems like localhost can not be resolved.  But what is strange is, when I do
`$ host localhost`, I got `localhost.xxxx.xxx.com has address 127.0.0.1`.

and localhost:8888 works perfectly well, which was managed by MAMP, as I mentioned at the beginning.

So, why localhost:8888 can be resolved, but localhost:9200 can not?

Thanks everyone for helping out!